# ViewChild in Angular2 forces view refresh

Tags: angular, dom

I'm using ViewChild to access elements in the DOM. However, using this causes the window to refresh each time I click my element. In comparison, the same implementation using document.querySelector doesn't refresh the window. I prefer the ViewChild implementation as it seems more clean.

### Viewchild implementation

```
export class NavigationListComponent {
  @ViewChild('mdl-layout') drawer: any;
  @Input() unreadEmailCount: number;
  drawer: any;

  constructor() {
    let MaterialLayout: any;
  }

  toggleDrawer() {
    this.drawer.MaterialLayout.toggleDrawer();
  }

}
```

### document.querySelector implementation

```
export class NavigationListComponent {

  @Input() unreadEmailCount: number;
  drawer: any;

  constructor() {
    let MaterialLayout: any;
    this.drawer = document.querySelector('.mdl-layout');
  }

  toggleDrawer() {
    this.drawer.MaterialLayout.toggleDrawer();
  }

}
```